# stored procedure for postgres to get next immediate working date from holiday list

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure in postgres to update only about next working date ie., `cnwd` in column of table `ts_courtslip_cnwd` based on holiday table `holiday_t` using `holidaydate`.
How could you make it more effective way to function out....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cnwd_details()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
     counter record;
     sdcounter record;    
     cnt int;
currentdate date;    
  nextdate date;  
  mnxtdate date;  
  flag boolean;
BEGIN
flag:=false;
currentdate:= (SELECT to_date(to_char(now()::date,'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd'));

   FOR counter IN SELECT * FROM dblink('host=172.16.2.32 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=taphc port=5432','SELECT holidaydate FROM holiday_t where date_part(''year'', create_modify) = date_part(''year'', CURRENT_DATE) and display=''Y'' and holidaydate >= ''now()''::date ORDER BY holidaydate ASC ')AS subquery(holidaydate date)  LOOP --LIMIT 1
flag:=true;  

 if currentdate<=counter.holidaydate then
 RAISE NOTICE 'holiday_t table holidaydate column: %', currentdate<=counter.holidaydate;
     nextdate:= (SELECT to_date(to_char(counter.holidaydate::date + INTERVAL '1 DAY','yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd'));
    perform  dblink('host=172.16.2.32 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=periphery port=5432',format('update ts_courtslip_cnwd set cnwd ='''||nextdate||'''')) as subquery ;

    else 

    end if; 
    END LOOP;
    if flag=false then
     mnxtdate:= (SELECT to_date(to_char(now()::date + INTERVAL '1 DAY','yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd'));    
    perform  dblink('host=172.16.2.32 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=periphery port=5432',format('update ts_courtslip_cnwd set cnwd ='''||mnxtdate||'''')) as subquery ;
    else

    end if;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION cnwd_details()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Can you simplify the question by putting only the essentials? For example the use of dblink does not seem fundamental in the management of holidays.

Answer (score 0):

I can address part of your question to simplify the overall code. You are doing way to much work processing dates. Look at just one of your date 'conversions':

```
mnxtdate:= (SELECT to_date(to_char(now()::date + INTERVAL '1 DAY','yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```

First off a SELECT statement is not at all necessary, you can have direct assignment:

```
instead of 
SELECT to_date(to_char(now()::date + INTERVAL '1 DAY','yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd') into mnxtdate;
    
just do:
mnxtdate:= expression;  (more later)
```

Now a look at what the interpreter has to do resolving the statement.

1. call the function now() ==> get the internal representation of the
   current timestamp.
2. (...)::date ==> convert internal representation of timestamp from #1
   to internal representation a date.
3. + interval '1 DAY' ==> convert the internal date from #2 to a internal timestamp and add 1 day.
4. to_char(..., 'yyyy-mm-dd') ==> convert the internal timestamp from
   #3 to string with with format 'yyyy-mm_dd'.
5. to_date(..., 'yyyy-mm-dd') ==> convert the string from #4 into an
   internal representation of a date.
6. Store result of #5 in variable local variable mnxtdate.

A much simpler way eliminates the select altogether, is easier to write, easier to understand and eliminates most a lot on internal processing:

```
mnxtdate = (now() + interval '1 day')::date;
```

1. call the function now() ==> get the internal representation of the current timestamp.
2. + interval '1 day' ==> add 1 day to result of #1
3. (...)::date ==> convert result of #2 in internal representation of date.
4. Store result of #3 in variable local variable mnxtdate.

Note: You could also cast the timestamp before converting to date then just add 1. See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d8c289e805707d658ac988dbb3ea848f). You might want to spend some time reviewing [Postgres Date Processing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html).

---

The following shows your reworking date assignments - nothing else.

```
create table or replace function cnwd_details()
  returns void as
$body$
declare
    counter record;
    sdcounter record;    
    cnt int;
    currentdate date;    
    nextdate date;  
    mnxtdate date;  
    flag boolean;
begin
    flag:=false;
    currentdate:= now()::date; 
        
    for counter in (dblink('host=172.16.2.32 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=taphc port=5432','select holidaydate from holiday_t where date_part(''year'', create_modify) = date_part(''year'', current_date) and display=''y'' and holidaydate >= ''now()''::date order by holidaydate asc ')as subquery(holidaydate date)  
    loop  
        flag:=true;  
        
        if currentdate<=counter.holidaydate then
           raise notice 'holiday_t table holidaydate column: %', currentdate<=counter.holidaydate;
           nextdate:= (counter.holidaydate+interval '1 day')::date;
           perform  dblink('host=172.16.2.32 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=periphery port=5432',format('update ts_courtslip_cnwd set cnwd ='''||nextdate||'''')) as subquery ;
        end if; 
        
    end loop;
            
    if flag=false then
        mnxtdate:= (now()+interval '1 day')::date ;    
        perform  dblink('host=172.16.2.32 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=periphery port=5432',format('update ts_courtslip_cnwd set cnwd ='''||mnxtdate||'''')) as subquery ;
    end if;
end;
$body$
  language plpgsql volatile
  cost 100;
```

Comment: This looks like a good (if partial) answer. However, if you are not sure about the intent of a question, it is best to seek clarifications (and give meta-advice) in the comments first. Remember that when writing an answer you it is best to address the general reader, not the question author, and thus advice about how to ask questions is not really relevant.